# How to create sub level of dynamic navigation using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a dynamic navigation menu on Codeiginter which retrieve from MYSQL DB
Here is the description of navigation

**Parent table**

```
|---parent_id---link---title-----|
|---1-----------#------Parent1---|
|---2-----------#------Parent2---|
|---3-----------#------Parent3---|
```

**Children table**

```
|---children_id---fk_parent_id---title-------|
|--------1---------2-------------children1---|
|--------2---------2-------------children2---|
|--------3---------2-------------children3---|
```

**Sub Children table (This sub child will show when children was selected)**

```
|---sub_child_id--- fk_children_d ------title-------|
|------1--------------2-------------Sub Children1---|
|------2--------------2-------------Sub Children2---|
|------3--------------2-------------Sub Children3---|
```

**Navigation menu**

```
|---------|---------|--------|
| Parent1 |Parent2  |Parent3 |  
|---------|===++====|--------|
|=============++======================================|       
|---|Children1|-----|Children2|-----|Childrent3|------|
|-===================++===============================|
|-----------------|Sub Childrent1|--------------------|
|-----------------|Sub Childrent2|--------------------|
|-----------------|Sub Childrent3|--------------------|
```

Notes: **As my below code it work only on Children but it don't show on sub 
Children**

Here is my model function which to create some conditional for childrent and parent

```
function menu() {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("menu_parents");
        $q = $this->db->get();

        $final = array();
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {

                $this->db->select("*");
                $this->db->from("menu_childrent");
                $this->db->where("fk_p_id", $row->parents_id);
                $q = $this->db->get();
                if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
                    $row->children = $q->result();
                    foreach ($q->result() as $srow){
                        //This is the session problem which I want to select for my sub children from menus_children
                        $this->db->select("*");
                        $this->db->from("menu_sub_childrent");
                        $this->db->where("fk_m_child_id", $srow->m_child_id);
                        $q = $this->db->get();
                        if($q->num_rows()>0){
                            $row->sub_children = $q->result();
                        }
                    }
                }
                array_push($final, $row);
            }
        }

        return $final;
    }
```

Here is my view

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <?PHP foreach($menus as $menu): ?> 
                            <li class="dropdown megamenu-fullwidth"> 
                                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"> <?PHP echo $menu->title;?> <?PHP  if(isset($menu->children)):?><b class="caret"></b><?PHP endif;?></a>
                                 <?PHP  if(isset($menu->children)):?>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
                                        <?PHP foreach($menu->children as $child): ?>
                                            <li class="megamenu-content">
                                                <ul class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                                                    <li class="no-border"><p><strong><?PHP echo $child->title;?></strong></p></li>

                                                        <?PHP  if(isset($menu->sub_children)):?> 
                                                            <?PHP foreach($menu->sub_children as $sub_children): ?> 
                                                                <li><a href="#"> <?PHP echo $sub_children->title;  ?><br></a></li>
                                                            <?PHP endforeach;  ?>
                                                        <?PHP endif;?>

                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        <?PHP endforeach;  ?>
                                    </ul>
                                 <?PHP  endif; ?>
                            </li>
                    <?PHP endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

Here is i Use Var_dump()

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[22]
      public 'parents_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'linke' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'title' => string 'parent1' (length=7)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[23]
      public 'parents_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'linke' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'title' => string 'parent2' (length=7)
      public 'children' => 
        array (size=6)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[26]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[25]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[27]
              ...
          3 => 
            object(stdClass)[28]
              ...
          4 => 
            object(stdClass)[29]
              ...
          5 => 
            object(stdClass)[30]
              ...
      public 'sub_children' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[33]
              ...
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[24]
      public 'parents_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'linke' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'title' => string 'parent1' (length=7)
```

Thanks advance for your help Sir

Comment: First point: Make your live easier and use one query for the whole navigation, instead of nested queries in loops. And the second one is: In your loops, youe are overriding $q.

Comment: I've try to create different of @q and $row it still not work.i amn't understand much about this

Comment: Pleas show a print_r($final) to see, that the array ist filled up right.

Comment: Oh when I used var_dump() function it doesn't show any value of my array. as my nest loop and mysql clause it show be show up why it doesn't show

Comment: Good look and try one query for the navigation, in the end it is easier.

Comment: I can't do that if I use one query from BD how can I create some conditional for Ul and Li I really don't understand about that. I've know, I should not use loop in query but I can't create the conditional for Ul and li and sub lij. so do you have any tutorial for create navigation by using that structures

Comment: I haven't a tutorial. Make one query by joining your «sub tables». You will get one object. Iterate over this object and make the decision if it's a main, children or sub_children. It is a main point, when children and sub_children are empty, a children, when children filled up, but not sub_children, etc.

Comment: they are all in array and we will used nested if to check but how can I know when it is main and when children and how to filled an the children or each parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a result that looks something like this:

[image]

And to do that, you first need to modify your table to be something like this:

[image]

Once you have this, you can then create a model like this of which you can then send to your controller, then your view:

```
class Nav_m extends MY_Model {

    private $menus;
    private $keys_to_skip = array();

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function menus() {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("nav");
        $this->q = $this->db->get();
        if ($this->q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $this->q->result_array();
        }
    }

    public function navigation($selected = null) {
        $this->menus = $this->menus();
        $out = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">';
        foreach ($this->menus as $k => $menu) {

//            var_dump($this->keys_to_skip);
            if (!in_array($k, $this->keys_to_skip)) {
                $class = (strcasecmp($menu['text'], $selected) == 0 ) ? "active " : "";
                $out .= $this->check_children($menu, $class);
            }
        }
        $out .= "</ul>";
        return $out;
    }

    function check_children($menu, $class) {

        if ($this->hasChildren($menu['id'])) {

            $class .="dropdown megamenu-fullwidth";
            $out = "<li class='$class'> <a href='{$menu['link']}'class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>" . $menu['text'] . "<b class='caret'></b>" . "</a>";
            $out .= $this->getChildren($menu['id']);
            $out .= "</li>";
        } else {
            $out = "<li class='$class'>";
            if ($menu['link'] != null) {
                $out .= "<a href='{$menu['link']}'>{$menu['text']}</a>";
            } else {
                $out .= "<span>" . $menu['text'] . "</span>";
            }
            $out .= "</li>";
        }
        return $out;
    }

    private function hasChildren($menu_id) {
        foreach ($this->menus as $menu) {
            if ($menu['show_condition'] && $menu['parent'] == $menu_id) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    private function getChildren($parent_id) {
        $has_subcats = FALSE;
        $out = "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
        $out .= "<li class='megamenu-content'>";
        foreach ($this->menus as $k => $menu) {
            if ($menu['show_condition'] && $menu['parent'] == $parent_id) {
                array_push($this->keys_to_skip, $k);
                $has_subcats = TRUE;
                $out .="<ul class='col-lg-2  col-sm-2 col-md-2 unstyled noMarginLeft'>";
                $out .= $this->check_childrens($menu, "");
                $out .= "</ul>";
            }
        }
        $out .= "</li>";
        $out .= "</ul>";
        return ( $has_subcats ) ? $out : FALSE;
    }

    function check_childrens($menu, $class) {

        if ($this->hasChildren($menu['id'])) {

            $class .="dropdown";
            $out = "<li><p><strong>".$menu['text']."</strong></p>";
            $out .= $this->getChildrens($menu['id']);
            $out .= "</li>";

        } else {
            $out = "<li class='$class'>";
            if ($menu['link'] != null) {
                $out .= "<a href='{$menu['link']}'>{$menu['text']}</a>";
            } else {
                $out .= "<span>" . $menu['text'] . "</span>";
            }
            $out .= "</li>";
        }
        return $out;
    }

    private function getChildrens($parent_id) {
        $out ='';
        foreach ($this->menus as $k => $menu) {
            if ($menu['show_condition'] && $menu['parent'] == $parent_id) {
                $out .= $this->check_childrens($menu, '');
                array_push($this->keys_to_skip, $k);
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct answer Thanks you very much Sir,
My Problem 2 months now it was solved.

I'm really thanks you.